# Django Custom Management Script: Deleting all migrations and database in one single command

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to write a management script for django polling app..
the command should delete all the `migrations` and `pycache`, and `dbfile` so that i can start out again later new with new migrations....

my file is `management/commands/removemigrations.py` below:

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError
from polls.models import Question as Poll

class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Delete migrations, pycache, dbfile, and all unwanted file'

    def add_arguments(self, parser):


    def handle(self, *args, **options):
```

I am very new in django, can anyone help me to craft this script? I am very new.. Thanks

Comment: why would you need to delete all migrations?

Comment: Before deleting any migration make sure your also revert the database. You can revert the database using migration command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using unix based system, you could just use the bash commands:

```
find . -path "\*/migrations/\*.py" -not -name "\__init__.py" -delete    
find . -path "\*/migrations/\*.pyc"  -delete
```

from the directory where manage.py is located.

you can read more about it at:
https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/26/how-to-reset-migrations.html

Comment: The back slashes in the file path seem to break these commands on macOS. The following worked for me:


find . -path "\*/migrations/\*.pyc"  -delete

find . -path "*/migrations/*.pyc"  -delete